# Java - Jetty - How to programmatically manage assets libs, css, img etc in Jetty-11 classpath outside web application root

Tags: java, jetty-11

1. I have a web application that is deployed on external jetty server. NOT using embedded jetty.
2. Requirement, need a Java rest endpoint to manage assets like lib, js, css, image file etc in jetty folders that are outside my application web root.
3. Manage assets means, ability endpoints to upload assets, update assets, delete assets.
   Request help as to how i can achieve the same

A simple Rest endpoint can only access folders under web root.

Comment: "A simple Rest endpoint can only access folders under web root."  That is not true and in general any Java program can potentially have access to the full file system.

Comment: I suppose you are using a default handler which restricts path-traversal to other folders for security reasons. But you can access anything the java process user can access when writing your own handlers